# C# MySQLDataReader returns same string for all rows

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm trying to extract values from a table and the MySQLDataReader doesn't seem to want to cooperate with me.

```
conn = new MySqlConnection(Credentials);
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(), cmd2 = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd2.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM test";
cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test (test) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(8);";
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ToString());
}
conn.Close();
```

The `INSERT` works as it should, as the table has been filled with the numbers 1-8 after checking the table, but this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ToString());
}
```

returns this in the console

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader
```

Comment: Some unrelated tips: the connection, command and DataReader are all IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close the connection because it will be closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block. It is displaying the result of `ToString`, and the default implementation of that for any type that has not overridden it is to return the name of the object's type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to access the columns of the `SqlDataReader`.  You can read [Retrieve data using a DataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader).  The current code just calls `ToString()` on the reader, which just returns it's type.

You can extract data by:

```
reader.GetString(0)     // get a string in the first column
reader.GetInt32(1)      // get an integer in the second column
reader.GetValue(2)      // get an object in the third column
reader.GetDateTime(3)   // get a datetime   
reader.GetDouble(4)     // get a double

// or by index/indexing
reader["ColumnName"].ToString()  // get value by column name
reader[0].ToString()             // get value by index
```

So your code would become:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    // get the value from the first column
    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0));    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! That fixed the issue.